# Fully clear dalvik cache in Android 7

Tags: 7.0-nougat, 7.1-nougat, dalvik

In past versions, I used to delete all files in `/data/dalvik-cache` to clear the dalvik cache, which is the only directory that shows up in TWRP log:

```
Wiping /data/dalvik-cache
```

In Lollipop and Marshmallow where Android uses ART VM, the dalvik cache is often a gigabyte or so big, and more if you installed a lot of apps.

In Nougat, however, with 200+ total apps (system + user), the dalvik cache folder is less than 800 MB as large, so I doubt it contains all dalvik cache: some must be residing at somewhere else.

How do I clear all dalvik cache? They're useless when backed up in a recovery.

Comment: "backed up in recovery" suggests you're using a custom recovery (which?). If that's not too old, the "Wipe Dalvik cache" should already include wiping ART along. AFAIR, some recoveries even renamed that menu item to "wipe Dalvik/ART cache". Have you checked that?

Comment: @Izzy It only shows "clearing /data/dalvik-cache" in the (latest!) TWRP recovery log, which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: That part is missing in your question :) Maybe you move it there (feel free whatever sounds helpful from my comments), and we clean up comments? // Funnily, even the [corresponding TWRP FAQ](https://twrp.me/faq/whattowipe.html) doesn't clarify this. [This related question](/q/179263/16575) confirms the suspicion in my previous comment. That the logs don't explicitly mention ART might be simply a place forgotten in development.